# How to map a servlet filter on /* in Jetty?

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, servlet-filters, web.xml

I have a servlet filter which I want to map to http://127.0.0.1:8888/ in Jetty. I have put a servlet filter mapping with url pattern `/*`. However, the filter is not called. I also tried with `/` mapping. It does not work either. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Is it a tomcat server? You can try bundling your app as root.war and deploy it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you name your war `root.war` it will be deployed to the root / context.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Deploy_Web_Applications

Comment: 2 things, first, I use jetty because it's the default server in the GWT-GAE plugin for eclipse, so I have no Idea how to do that. Second, I dont think the GAE uses jetty, so how could I fix this for the GAE.

Comment: Consider asking another question, so others can help you with GWT and GAE specific items. This question was generic and was answered to the best of our knowledge, given the details.

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect requests from "/" to "/urlToRedirect" and handle "/urlToRedirect" by special servlet. Like in example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Servlet frontend = new Frontend();

    Server server = new Server(8080);
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(frontend), "/index");
    context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(frontend), "/auth");

    ResourceHandler resource_handler = new ResourceHandler();
    resource_handler.setDirectoriesListed(false);
    resource_handler.setResourceBase("static");

    RewriteHandler rewriteHandler = new RewriteHandler();
    rewriteHandler.setRewriteRequestURI(true);
    rewriteHandler.setRewritePathInfo(true);
    rewriteHandler.setOriginalPathAttribute("requestedPath");
    RedirectRegexRule rule = new RedirectRegexRule();
    rule.setRegex("/");
    rule.setReplacement("/index");
    rewriteHandler.addRule(rule);

    HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
    handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[]{rewriteHandler, resource_handler, context});
    server.setHandler(handlers);

    server.start();
    server.join();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Jetty web-app deployment doc](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Deploy_Web_Applications) mentions that the wep-app can be packaged as `root.war` to have a root context `/`

Answer (score 0):

Each application in jetty is deployed to its context - meaning it have some part after the slash - i.e   http://127.0.0.1:8888/context/ - your servlet mapping is realitve to the last slash - not the one before context

As mentioned in the other answers you must deploy the application as root.war to overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

Optionally you could create a directory with name `root` under `$JETTY_HOME/webapps` and copy your web app contents into `$JETTY_HOME/webapps/root`