# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [] in DispatcherServlet while file is available

Tags: java, spring, embedded-jetty

I'm getting this error again and again...

web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>brb</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>brb</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>brb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

brb-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd"
   default-lazy-init="false">

<context:component-scan base-package="spring"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="" />
    <property name="suffix" value="" />
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
</bean>

<bean name="simple" class="spring.SimpleBean">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="1"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="1"/>
</bean>
```

Controller class is like this:

```
@Controller
public class BrbController{


@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = GET)
public String index() {
    System.out.println(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("index.jsp")); // i check is file is available, actually I've coppied it in all resource directories presented
    return "index.jsp";
}
```

I'm trying to ger this simple application running under embedded Jetty, but for some reason spring mvc can't see the view files.

UPDATE: I'm trying to open "localhost:9123/"

Comment: While querying using *what* URI?

Comment: Sorry. Didn't mension it. Just localhost:9123/

Comment: Have you mapped your application to root? In other words does 'localhost:9123/' resolve to your web app? If not this may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219148/how-to-map-a-servlet-filter-on-in-jetty

Comment: I checked: it's my application for sure, there are WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/index.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet-284d5543'
Also some static response bodies work just fine

Answer (score 0):

*Note:* Untested.

First, try to map your `<url-pattern>` in your `web.xml`:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>brb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If you need a context-root-path, then specify a context name on `<url-pattern>`:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>brb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Secondly, your `RequestMapping` should have a `context-path` mapping.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/start", method = GET)
```

I hope this helps.